# Mybatis 3.0.5 insert/update statement mapping with multiple inputs

Tags: java, mapping, persistence, mybatis

Maybe I am missing something obvious, but I cannot get a simple mapped insert statement executing successfully.

Using the following interface

```
public interface CustomItemMapper 
{
    Integer insert(CustomItem item, @Param("extra") String someparam);
}
```

and the following XML mapping

```
  <insert id="insert" useGeneratedKeys="false" parameterType="map" keyProperty="id">
    insert into CustomItem (id, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
        values (#{id}, #{field2}, #{field3}, #{field4}, #{field5}, #{extra})
  </insert>
```

and this code

```
SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = (SqlSessionFactory) servletContext.getAttribute("SqlSessionFactory");
SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
try 
{ 
    CustomItemMapper mapper = session.getMapper(CustomItemMapper.class); 
    mapper.update(item);
    session.commit();
} 
finally 
{ 
    session.close(); 
}
```

I get the following debug output:

```
Checked out connection 368716606 from pool.
ooo Connection Opened
==>  Executing: insert into CustomItem (id, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
==> Parameters: null, null, null, null, null, actual_value_of_extra(String)
xxx Connection Closed
Returned connection 368716606 to pool.
```

followed by the SQL exception (cannot enter null into the `id` column).

So the only value that was passed in properly is the extra supplied string. I have verified that the field names are correct and object is not null at this point and the fields are populated properly.

I also tried using `parameterType="CustomItem"` instead of `parameterType="map"` but the result did not change.

I would appreciate if someone could let me know what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I get into the same problem with insert statements, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the other parameter in your mapper method.  I'm assuming CustomItem is a Java bean, with get methods for field1 etc.  As already mentioned, change your parameter type, so that it is not Map.

From mybatis [documentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://mybatis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/en/MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf&rct=j&q=mybatis%203%20user%20guide&ei=1MOMTp7eKayEsgL_oZykBA&usg=AFQjCNG4JyUPOutyZpVerNf7meG_VlGq-Q&sig2=WBQ2mVgwb89fzjsB1C93jA&cad=rja),

> You can pass multiple parameters to a mapper method. If you do, they
>   will be named by their position in the parameter list by default, for
>   example: #{1}, #{2} etc. If you wish to change the name of the
>   parameters (multiple only), then you can use the @Param(“paramName”)
>   annotation on the parameter.

So, change your Mapper,

```
public interface CustomItemMapper 
{
    Integer insert(@Param("item")CustomItem item, @Param("extra") String someparam);
}
```

and change your xml to,

```
 <insert id="insert" useGeneratedKeys="false" parameterType="map" keyProperty="id">
    insert into CustomItem (id, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
        values (#{id}, #{item.field1}, #{item.field2}, #{item.field3}, #{item.field4}, #{extra})
  </insert>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have seen that section in the manual, and thought about the change in the interface. What I could not come up is the second part (i.e. the representation of the `item` in the xml).

Comment: np, it is OGNL.  Search for Dynamic SQL in the user guide for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing an instance of `CustomItem` into the `update()` call, then the `parameterType` should definitely be the fully-qualified name of the class, and not `"map"` - you would use the latter only if you were passing a `java.util.Map` to the `insert()` method.

Comment: Manual (page 25) says parameterType is either a fully-qualified name or an alias. I tried both "map" (because that is how multiple parameters are passed to `select` statements) and the alias but results are the same. To remove any doubt, I tried the fully qualified name a moment ago and nothing changed.